# What does "to one extent or another" mean?

Tags: expressions

Example:

> *The German Ideology* is the first work that can be read as a reliable
> exposition of the essential views of Marxism (except in
> economics). In that sense it is the first “Marxist" work, all previous
> writings being anticipations, forerunners, or harbingers **to one extent
> or another**.

Comment: It means "to a greater or lesser extent."

Comment: It can be read as "to one *degree* or another" that is *more or less*.

Comment: It more or less means the same thing as "more or less".